# CSS 3 Keyframes animation doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css, animation

I have a little animation which can be seen here
http://jsfiddle.net/LcvS4/1/

This one is using @keyframes

```
@keyframes move {
     0% {
         left: 0%;
     }
     100% {
         left: 100%;
     }
 }
```

This works great in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome. I haven't figured out why. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-webkit-` vendor prefix

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
     0% {
         left: 0%;
     }
     100% {
         left: 100%;
     }
 }
```

You'll also need to add it to any animation properties (as well as keeping those without it for support in other browsers), e.g:

`-webkit-animation-name:move;`

[**More on vendor prefixes:**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm)

> CSS vendor prefixes or CSS browser prefixes are a way for browser
>   makers to add support for new CSS features in a sort of testing and
>   experimentation period. Browser prefixes are used to add new features
>   that may not be part of a formal specification and to implement
>   features in a specification that hasn’t been finalized.

[**The MDN article on `animation` is also a good read**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)